# Using a Button to Download A Table From Email Sent With PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, html-email

When PHP is called a postgres query builds a table and sends it in an email. I initially had used fputcsv to download rather than send the email but for some reason it stopped working (405 Not Allowed). In fact, I have been unsuccessful in simply getting the table to display without any additional actions. I assume it has something to do with server interaction. Regardless, the query to build the table and email it still works so I am trying to add a button beneath the table that would allow for the table to download. In html and javascript I can make this happen with the exportTableToCSV function. However, since I cannot work outside of the `<?php` tag, I am unable to get this to fit and work within the PHP email page.

Here is what I have --

```
<?php
{
$datea= $_POST["userDatea"];
$media= $_POST["userMedia"];
$datez= $_POST["userDatez"];
$media_names = "'".implode( "%','", $media)."%'";
$myemail = 'myemail@recipient.com';
$email_address = 'reports@sender.com';

$message = "
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>Daily Media Summary</title>

            </head>
            <body>";

$body .= "<table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='3' width='1360'>";
$body .= "<tr><td width: '650'>Date</td><td width: '140'>Total Plays</td><td width: '140'>Total Stores</td><td width: '140'>PPH</td></tr>";


// Create connection
$conn = pg_connect("host=ipofhost port=portofhost dbname=name user=username password=pword");

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
  echo "Did not connect.\n";
  exit;
}

$partsresult = pg_query($conn, "SELECT
date (b.starttime),
Count(b.starttime) as Plays,
Count(distinct(b.playerid)) as Stores

FROM
public.billing b,
public.medias m

WHERE
b.mediaitemid = m.id and
m.name LIKE any (array[$media_names]) and
b.starttime >= date('$datea') and 
b.starttime < date('$datez')+1 and
m.startdate >  '2015-01-01'

GROUP BY
date (b.starttime)

ORDER BY
date (b.starttime);");

$day = date("D"); 
if($day == 'Mon') { 

            if (!$partsresult) {
              echo "Query failed.\n";
              exit;
            }

              while ($partsrow = pg_fetch_row($partsresult)) { 
              //$body .= "";
              $divide = ($partsrow[1]/$partsrow[2]);
              $math = round($divide/7.2, 2);
              $body .= "<tr><td width: '750'> $partsrow[0] </td>";
              $body .= "<td width: '140'> $partsrow[1] </td>";
              $body .= "<td width: '140'> $partsrow[2] </td>";
              $body .= "<td width: '75'> $math </td></tr>";
             };


}

else { 

            if (!$partsresult) {
              echo "Query failed.\n";
              exit;
            }

              while ($partsrow = pg_fetch_row($partsresult)) { 
              //$body .= "";
              $divide = ($partsrow[1]/$partsrow[2]);
              $math = round($divide/10.7, 2);
              $body .= "<tr><td width: '750'> $partsrow[0] </td>";
              $body .= "<td width: '140'> $partsrow[1] </td>";
              $body .= "<td width: '140'> $partsrow[2] </td>";
              $body .= "<td width: '140'> $partsrow[3] </td>";
              $body .= "<td width: '140'> $partsrow[4] </td>";
              $body .= "<td width: '75'> $math </td></tr>";
             };


}


pg_close($conn);


            $message .= $body . "</table>";
            $message .= $body . "<input type=button onclick=mybutton()/>";//not sure how to make this happen?
            $message .= $body . "</body>";
            $message .= $body . "</html>";

{
$to = $myemail;
$email_subject = "daily media item report";
$email_body = "$message";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html;';
$headers .= "From: sender@sender.com";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers, "-f reports@data.com");
//redirect to the 'thank you' page

}
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you looking to send the table via email or just want it to be downloaded?

Comment: I want to be able to download the table from the email that was sent. I had it downloading but it stopped working.

Comment: To be able to download from the email, there are two approaches. First, you can generate the Excel and attach it in the email that you are sending. Second, you can provide with a download link in the email. The second approach gives the flexibility to have an up-to-date Excel download, whereas the first is ideal in case you need to document the data that was sent. What are you looking for? Based on that I will answer.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, my answer would be that I would like a download link in the email.

Comment: In this case, you will create the desired table and add it in the email body. In that email, you will give the download button/link. Once clicked, it will take to your website where the table will re-generated and then presented as a PDF or Excel. I prefer PDF as it cannot be modified. In the next comment, I will give you the procedure. In case you need clarifications on how to execute, do let me know.

Comment: First step, recommended PHPMailer to send the HTML table via email with the download link. In that email, add a link to download with href to a page on your website that populates data in a PDF/Excel. For PDF, you can use mPDF. For Excel, you can use table2excel. But this will have to show the table first as it only download the shown HTML table.

Comment: Thank you, I am testing PHP Mailer but i have yet to successfully integrate it. I believe that your solution to have the link open another page will result in the same 405 error. I am looking into solutions on the server side to this as I believe it is the root issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157168/discussion-between-mohammed-akhtar-zuberi-and-kevmoe).